# If logged in with remember me then no new csrf token can manually be generated. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, session

Here's the screen of result in browser console when I login with remember me and after the session expiration try to logout. As we see it doesn't work as expected.

[image]

Here's the another screen of result when I login without remember me and after the session expiration try to logout. As we can see, it works good and as expected.

[image]

That problem forces user to click on logout twice.

At first time it does a page reload and the csrf token is updated automatically.

At second time it finally logouts.

But that's very bad.

Here's the js code which does the logout request.

```
function logOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/"+lang+"/refreshToken",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('New csrf token === ' + result.token)
            $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value', result.token);
            $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', result.token);

            ajaxLogoutRequest()
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //console.log(xhr);
            console.log('New csrf token === ' + result.token);
            if (result.token === undefined){
                //logOut(e);
                location.reload();
                ajaxLogoutRequest();
                console.log("status code is " + result.status);
            }
        }
    })
}

function ajaxLogoutRequest(){
    var formData = $('#logout-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/logout',
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(data){
            location.reload();
        },
        error:function (data) {
            console.log(data.status)
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the routes

```
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'locale', 'prefix' => '{locale?}'], function () {  
    ...
    Route::get('/privacy', 'Front\StaticPagesController@privacy')->name('privacy');
    Route::get('/refreshToken','Auth\LoginController@refreshToken');
    ...
});
```

The LoginController methods:

```
public function logout(Request $request)  //this is the overrided method of trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    //some new important actions
    if (Auth::user()) {
        User::where('id', Auth::id())->update(array('signed_in_for_remember_me' => null));

        //the same code from which was overrided
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
    }

    return response()->json(["token"=>csrf_token()], 200);
}

public function refreshToken(Request $request)
{
    session()->regenerateToken();
    return response()->json(["token"=>csrf_token()], 200);
}
```

and the session config file's needed code (my opinion, if you have another point, let me know)

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 1,/*1 is just for testing, after that make 15 again*/
'expire_on_close' => true,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => null,
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'http_only' => true,
```

Logout works perfect for all cases, except when I login with remember me and the session limit is already expired.

Here's more detailed info

```
1) logout without expired session and without remember me enabled (works as expected)
2) logout with expired session and without remember me enabled (works as expected)
3) logout without expired session and with remember me enabled (works as expected)
4) logout with expired session and with remember me enabled (fails until the page is reloaded and user tries to logout again)
```

How this problem can be fixed? What variants do you have?

IMPORTANT! I use laravel 5.4

---

EDITED

---

I work with XAMPP, so there are three logs for apache

1. access.log
2. error.log
3. php_error_log

in first one I found only one line which gave me nearly nothing helpful,
or just I don't see the importance of gotten result.

```
"POST /logout HTTP/1.1" 500 29043 "http://localhost/am/privacy" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36"
```

the two other files has no info about the needed error.

here's the browser's Network tool screen

[image]

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: @ADyson I know that error 500 is nearly meaningless cause we can't know what it's actually meaning. But anyway I have important debugging info. The new token won't come when I use remember me. I noticed that new token won't come in cases when session isn't expired too. But in second variant it not harms cause there's no reason for TokenMismatchException but in my case it has a harm, cause as I can see, the problem is "remember me works instead of session lifetime, so expired token won't be updated". I noticed that XSRF-TOKEN Cookie autodeletes from list and won't be recreated until page reload

Comment: `we can't know what it's actually meaning`...yes you can, if you look at your error logs. Your other debugging info is useful but the problems seem to be a symptom of the fact that this request is failing and returning 500. So you need to work out why that is, and fix it, and then see if that resolves the rest of it. Now you mention TokenMismatchException, but when is that coming? [edit] the question to 1) include the exact exception message shown in the logs from your 500 error, 2) tidy up the code formatting, and 3) explain how TokenMismatchException is related.

Comment: @ADyson there's no error logs for this issue. I have a page which have another errors.. so that errors are adding to error logs list but this one won't be added. So I don't see any use of error logs yet.

Comment: Maybe it's a webserver error then - did you check webserver logs as well as PHP logs? Or maybe an error message is shown in the raw response to the `/logout` request - did you try to view that in the browser's Network tool?

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question with some new info.